# Flask app giving "Application Error" when hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

*Just a precursor, I've looked at very similar questions on Stack Overflow and tried all the solutions suggested there however none of them worked so I'm assuming it's something else I'm not getting. Also for various reasons I'm restricted to working exclusively online, and I can't use any CLI commands I can only use the website as an interface.*

I've been building a web-app with Flask (it works fine on repl.it), and I went to try host it on Heroku (connected through GitHub) but keep getting an "Application Error" when it loads with these two items in the log:

```
2022-08-09T08:48:18.336638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=heroku-learning-temporary.herokuapp.com request_id=395ddf03-0a6e-4656-a185-09d6258ecfa9 fwd="124.171.47.188,165.225.114.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-09T08:48:19.449634+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=heroku-learning-temporary.herokuapp.com request_id=95dc333b-3e5c-46bf-867d-d8444ac3d35a fwd="124.171.47.188,165.225.114.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

So I built a really simple Flask app just to try identify the problem but got the exact same error logs. The really simple flask app I built looked like this:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return("Hello there")
 
 if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(port=5000)
```

wgsi.py

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

and Procfile

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

All of these are from the tutorial [here](https://towardsdev.com/deploying-basic-flask-app-on-heroku-c27f087802c2) with the exception of the requirements.txt which I added 'cause otherwise it failed in the build stage.

Is there something I'm not doing right? Or is it going wrong 'cause I'm not using the CLI but just using the website?

Also if it's easier to view the code on GitHub my repository is [here](https://github.com/LukeCampbell5853/Heroku-testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your procfile to:
**web: gunicorn app:app**
your wsgi.py file can be deleted

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I'm getting the same messages but it is at least running with fewer files so thanks heaps for the idea.

Comment: Hi again, i read heroku docs and see, port of wsgi apps cant be set by user, prove to quit port in your app.run() method